# Access object constructor created ArrayList Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, scope

I'm working on a project where I need to create an ArrayList inside the constructor of a class. I have done this as so:

```
ArrayList<Users> grouping;
public userGroup(){
grouping = new ArrayList<Users>();      
}
```

This is working as intended.
I declared a new userGroup administrators in my 'Main.java'

```
    userGroup administrators = new userGroup();
```

However I now need to access the ArrayList from Main.java,
like this:

```
        /*Last Item in administrators Object's ArrayList*/.setUserType("user");
```

I'm not sure how to do this..
I have tried

```
administrators.grouping.setUserType("user");
```

But don't know what to try next.

Comment: If you want to call the method on the last element of the list, it would be `administrators.grouping.get(administrators.grouping.size()-1).setUserType("user");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`administrators.grouping` will give you the list. if you want to access an element from it, you need to get it first, and only then you can call `setUserType` on it.

```
administrators.grouping.get(i).setUserType("user");
```

where `i` is the index of the element you want from the list.

Also- it's good practice to encapsulate the fields of your class, i.e. don't access the field directly but set them as private and add a getter method:

```
public class UserGroup {
 private List<Users> grouping;
 public userGroup(){
  grouping = new ArrayList<Users>();      
 }
 public ArrayList<Users> getGrouping() {
  return this.grouping; // changed l to ;
 }
}
```

And then:

```
administrators.getGrouping().get(i).setUserType("user");
```

Comment: So could I then to get the last element use
int i = administrators.getGrouping().size();
administrators.getGrouping().get(i).setUserType("user");

Comment: @TaylorMudd - `i` should be size minus one - remember the indexes start at 0

Answer (score 1):

You should write getter for grouping field.

```
class UserGroup {
   ArrayList<Users> grouping;

   public UserGroup(){
       grouping = new ArrayList<Users>();      
    }

   public ArrayList<Users> getGrouping() {
      return this.grouping;
  }
}
```

And in main

```
UserGroup administrators = new UserGroup();
int size = administrators.getGrouping().size();
// I recommend you to check if size is not 0 here
administrators.getGrouping().get(size - 1).setUserType("user");
```